# What is this creature biting on the Cerritos?

Tags: star-trek, aliens, character-identification, star-trek-lower-decks

In a brief shot on the opening of the show Lower Decks, a huge insectoid life form is seen biting down on a warp nacelle of the USS Cerritos and being carried along with it- is this alien based on anything shown on TOS or any of the spinoffs?

[image: huge insectoid biting on a warp nacelle of the USS Cerritos]

Answer (score 8):

The incident is almost certainly inspired by the TNG Episode Galaxy's child.  But it is not the same species of space creature that feeds on ship energy.

Answer (score -1):

I looked up the USS Cerritos on Memory Alpha, it named this alien as a 'Space Grub", or on a more detailed page, a "larval space creature".

Comment: Memory Alpha is a fan-written website. These names appears to just be generic descriptions written by people with no special connection to the show.